# Javascript : How to keep defined object descriptor of original objects after mixing them up?

Tags: javascript, descriptor

let say i have thoses two objects for wich i set descriptor on each props :

```
var readonly = {
     libName: _libName,
     libVersion: _libVersion,
     createStage: _createStage,
     renderer: _renderer
};
Object.keys(readonly).forEach(function (prop) {
    Object.defineProperty(readonly, prop, {
        writable: false

    });
});
```

and

```
var writable = {
    rendererOptions: _rendererOptions
};

Object.keys(writable).forEach(function (prop) {
    Object.defineProperty(writable, prop, {
        writable: false
    });
});
```

I then want to merge the two object with assign, but the descriptor are not kept. I don't know if its normal, as a third object is created. If so, how could i work that up to keep the descriptor? Here is what i am getting (this is only an example BTW) :

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(writable, "rendererOptions"));
//gives Object {value: Object, writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: true}

var o = Object.assign(readonly, writable);

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, "rendererOptions"));
//gives Object {value: Object, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}
```

Thanks for any help you can give. And if you have a better solution, 'am all for it.

Comment: Seems like you're looking for something like the `completeAssign` example under MDN's article on [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Copying_accessors).  The article should also help explain the behavior that you're seeing from the code above.

Comment: "*a third object is created*" - nope. `o === readonly`.

Comment: I believe what you actually want is `var o = Object.freeze(Object.assign({}, readonly, writeable))`

Comment: @Noah Freitas - Thanks, created my own based on this and it works! Should change this as your answer so i can accept it

Comment: @Bergi, you are right, i got to pass an empty object as first param to have a new object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my comment as an answer:

Seems like you're looking for something like the [completeAssign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Copying_accessors) example under MDN's article on Object.assign. The article should also help explain the behavior that you're seeing from the code above